# "List" Object Not Callable, Syntax Error for Text-Based RPG

Tags: python

I'm having issues (still) with generating a random object, in this case a random herb found by foraging. Here's the code for the function:

```
def collectPlants(self):
    if self.state == 'normal':
        print"%s spends an hour looking for medicinal plants." % self.name
        if random.choice([0,1]):
            foundHerb = random.choice(herb_dict)
            print "You find some %s." % foundHerb
            return random.choice(herb_dict)
        else: print"%s doesn't find anything useful." % self.name
```

and the dict block:

```
herb_dict = [
    ("Aloe Vera", Player().health == Player().health + 2),
    ("Cannabis", Player().state == 'high'),
    ("Ergot", Player().state == 'tripping')
]
```

Sorry for the clandestine examples. Herb is also a class with three parameters: (self, name, effect).

How do I generate a random herb from the dict when the collectPlants function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`random.choice` is a method so if you want to call it you need to use `()` instead of `[]`. Also to access an element in the list you need to use `[]` not `()`.

And for your case, replace the `return random.choice[herb_dict("")]` with `return random.choice(herb_dict)` can meet you need and it will randomly return an element in `herb_dict`.

But I think the logic of you method has some problem.

```
print "You find some %s." % herb.name
player.hasHerb()
```

The above two statements will never be executed.

Also you can use `if random.choice([0, 1]):` instead of `if random.randint(0,1) == 1:`.

Comment: And `herb_dict` isn't actually a `dict`

Comment: Yes. I say *access elements in a list* not a *dict*. @monkey

Comment: Right, so how do I execute the print line?

Comment: Assign the choice result to a variable. And then execute the `print`. And then return the variable.@Velcrode

Comment: I assigned random.choice[herb_dict] to foundHerb, put it before the print and returned the variable, but the "instancemethod object is unsubscriptable" error results. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have said in my answer. Use `random.choice(herb_dict)` not `[]`.@Velcrode

Comment: One more issue, it seems: now the error message is, "Not all arguments converted during string formatting." :(

Comment: Yeah. It should be this. For example, the `foundHerb` now is a tuple of 2 elements. And the format can only accept one. You may want `print "You find some %s." % foundHerb[0]`. And `return foundHerb`. Don't do what you have written. @Velcrode

Comment: @zhangyangyu Yes! Thank you. You've been a tremendous help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like below, as random.choice needs a Sequence to pick a random value.

```
random.choice(herb_dict)
```

With the result above, you would get a tuple and could use [index] to access the element, for instance to access the first element in that, use random.choice(herb_dict)[0]

Comment: The `herb_dict` is a list not a dict.