# Adding a Random Item to a List for a Text-Based RPG

Tags: python

This is concatenated to the question I asked earlier today (["List" Object Not Callable, Syntax Error for Text-Based RPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738110/list-object-not-callable-syntax-error-for-text-based-rpg)). Now my dilemma resides in adding the herb to the player's herb list.

```
self.herb = []
```

is the starting herb list. The function collectPlants:

```
def collectPlants(self):
    if self.state == 'normal':
    print"%s spends an hour looking for medicinal plants." % self.name
        if random.choice([0,1]):
        foundHerb = random.choice(herb_dict)
        print "You find some %s." % foundHerb[0]
        self.herb.append(foundHerb)
        print foundHerb
    else: print"%s doesn't find anything useful." % self.name
```

with foundHerb being the random choice. How do I add this item to the list in a neat way (currently it prints the herb name, then "None") and allow for having several of the same herb?

Here's the herb class:

```
class herb:
    def __init__(self, name, effect):
        self.name = name
        self.effect = effect
```

Sample list of herbs (warning: immaturity):

```
herb_dict = [
    ("Aloe Vera", Player().health = Player().health + 2),
    ("Cannabis", Player().state = 'high'),
    ("Ergot", Player().state = 'tripping')
]
```

Comment: How is `foundHerb` formed? Also, do you mean `self.herb = []` (as that is a list. You're working with a string)

Comment: foundHerb = random.choice(herb_dict). I already have a list (not a dict, I know - misnomer) of herbs to be randomly found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list.

```
self.herb = []
foundHerb = 'something'
self.herb.append(foundHerb)
self.herb.append('another thing')
self.herb.append('more stuff')

print 'You have: ' + ', '.join(self.herb)
# You have: something, another thing, more stuff
```

---

EDIT: I found the code from which you get `foundHerb` in one of your other questions (please post it in this question too!), which is:

```
foundHerb = random.choice(herb_dict)
```

When I look at `herb_dict`:

```
herb_dict = [
    ("Aloe Vera", Player().health == Player().health + 2),
    ("Cannabis", Player().state == 'high'),
    ("Ergot", Player().state == 'tripping')
]
```

1. This is wrong, use `=` for assignment. `==` is for testing equality.
2. You need to use a function in the second item in these tuples.
3. Don't add the second item into the list. Like this:

   ```
   self.herb.append(foundHerb[0])
   ```

Comment: "Use a list" is correct and solves the current problem. "Read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)" might solve a bunch of future problems.

Comment: I've found that reading the tutorial hardly results in me retaining information, so instead I bang my head repeatedly against the keyboard and go on Stack Overflow so much more fluent people can reduce the chances of me developing head trauma.

Comment: @Velcrode That's... terrifying `:P` Anyway, glad you find this site helpful `:)`

Comment: @Velcrode Then something is wrong with your `collectPlants` function. Try `print foundHerb` and tell me what it prints.

Comment: Same thing, except it also prints [("Herb", "None")] when the herb is found rather than just when the other function ('inv') is called to display the list of herbs.

Comment: @Velcrode So `foundHerb` is `[("Herb", "None")]`? That's why `None` is being added to the list of herbs, of course. Where do you get `foundHerb`? Could you post the code from where you got it?

Comment: I just realized... "None" is taking the place of the second parameter in the herb class, which is effect. I assume? So now that's my quandary. How do I cut that bit out?

Comment: Could you explain the necessity of a lambda? Also, I threw in the equality test to negate the syntax error that arises from assigning in that block for some reason...

Comment: Alright, now the inv function returns a decently tidy ['Herb'] value. Now, to figure out how to use the herb...

Comment: @Velcrode You need to pass a function, not an assignment, because if you pass an assignment, it will give an error, as you have found, because an assignment is a statement, not a variable that you can call. You need to pass a function that contains that assignment so that you can call that function. (sorry for the delayed response, I was occupied by other things)

Comment: I did so. The problem now lies in the useHerb function, which seems to love returning "You don't have this herb." But these comments have gone on far too long, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your function, think what would happen if `random.choice([0,1])` was `0`. it would not run the `if` block, so no herb would ever be chosen. Perhaps in your function, you can `return False` to say that no herb was found. Then you can do this:

```
self.herb = []
myherb = collectPlants() # This will either contain a herb or False
if myherb: # If myherb is a plant (and it isn't False)
    self.herb.append(myherb)
```

Comment: In the other question I posed the collectPlants function is given. I did return the value foundHerb, but I'll try .append()